# Неточное значение у double

Tags: java

Есть код:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double a = 0.1, b = 0.2, c = a + b;
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

Я учился в школе и знаю, что `с == 0.3`, но вот Java так не считает:

```
0.30000000000000004
```

Или такой код:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double a = 0.1, b = 3.0, c = a * b;
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

Результат всё равно тот же:

```
0.30000000000000004
```

Почему так, что я делаю не так, и как от этого избавиться?

Comment: Потому что компьютер не может представить 0.1 + 0.2 = 0.3 внутри стандартного double в виду его архитектуры. У него есть ошибки точности, которые, если грубо, и позволяют запихнуть такие диапазоны в 32/64 бит.

Answer (score 3):

Дело в том, что `double` - это число 64 битов, и возможно точно определить только 2<sup>64</sup> разные числа. Поэтому, будут много чисел, без точной репрезентацией в `double`.

Более того, число `0.3` (и `0.1` и `0.2`) нельзя писать в двойчной системой счисления, будет бесконечно.

Самое близкое `double` от `0.1` - это

```
0.100000000000000005551115123126
```

Самое близкое `double` от `0.2` - это

```
0.200000000000000011102230246252
```

И вместе получится

```
0.300000000000000016653345369378
```

Самое близкое `double` от этого:

```
0.300000000000000044408920985006
```

Потом `System.out.println` покажет `0.30000000000000004`.

Answer (score 2):

У `double` существуют проблемы с точностью при арифметических операциях.
Тут все подробно рассказано http://habrahabr.ru/post/112953/

Answer (score 0):

Использовать BigDecimal вместо Double

подробно почитать можно [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320209/javawhy-should-we-use-bigdecimal-instead-of-double-in-the-real-world)

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы.